# How to set Windows to create a dedicated dump file without having a page file?

Tags: windows, pagefile

According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/how-to-determine-the-appropriate-page-file-size-for-64-bit-versions-of-windows#dedicated-dump-files):

> Computers that are running Microsoft Windows or Microsoft Windows
> Server usually must have a page file to support a system crash dump.
> System administrators can now create a dedicated dump file instead.
>
> A dedicated dump file is a page file that isn't used for paging.
> Instead, it is "dedicated" to back a system crash dump file ... use a
> dedicated dump file if you want a system crash dump but you don't want
> a page file.

However, the page I linked above, though it has some links, doesn't seem to have a link to a page showing ***how*** to set this dedicated dump file without a page file.

So how *is* it done?

Comment: This docs your referring to applies to Windows 10, that's a bit outdated. Im going to see if i can reach the technical writer because dedicated dump file is a bad term

Answer (score 1):

System Control Panel > Advanced tab > Startup and Recovery > Settings:

System failure:

- Select *Complete memory dump* from the drop down list
- Specify the file path in the Dump file text box

[image: Recovery tab]

Comment: Also, a complete memory dump could take a long time when a lot of memory is installed and the target disk is slow. I.e. You can figure it out by dividing 16GB (which is 16384MB) by 120MB/s, which is equivalent to 3 minutes (or to be exact 137sec) on a standard SATA-HDD for an additional reboot time.

Comment: Are you saying that you disabled page file and you still get a crash dump with this? If not, how does this address the question?

Answer (score 1):

In Addtion to Greg Askew Answer,

Additionally said, a complete memory dump could take a long time when a lot of memory is installed and the target disk is slow. I.e. You can figure it out by dividing 16GB (which is 16384MB) by 120MB/s, which is equivalent to 3 minutes (or to be exact 137sec) on a standard SATA-HDD for an additional reboot time.
Which might be critical and should be considered if you are talking about servers like databases or hyper-V servers with, for example, 96 GB or more memory.

And as a Second extension:
Usually, it's enough to use a short memory dump and look at it with a program called [BlueScreenViewer](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) from [Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net). There are other similar programs available, but most admins know about this one.
-To be honest, I am not affiliated with this company, but I have been utilizing this software for a considerable amount of time to troubleshoot issues and other coworkers known to me.

Comment: How does this address the question?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I want to state that current documentation indeed has mixed messages on the topic.

In the end, my understanding is - if you want a successful memory dump, **it is not recommended to have a dump file without a page file**.

The only fact we have is: the OS states explicitly that any memory dump is not guaranteed to contain complete information without a page file. This message appears for any type of memory dump while having no page file set in `Settings - System - About - [Advanced system settings]`

> Windows might not be able to record details that could help identify system errors because your current paging file is disabled or less than XXX megabytes.

Also there is a statement that implies you must have a page file in article [Configure system failure and recovery options in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/configure-system-failure-and-recovery-options#tips)

> To take advantage of the dump file feature, your paging file must be
> on the boot volume. If you've moved the paging file to another volume,
> you must move it back to the boot volume before you use this feature.

Though it is not 100% clear if this statement refers to all dump file options, or only to the last one mentioned in the article.

Also, in the same article, all options state explicitly you **must have a page file** (except the last one)

- **Complete memory dump**
  `[...] you must have a paging file on the boot volume [...]`
- **Kernel memory dump**
  `[...] you must have a pagefile large enough to accommodate your kernel memory [...]`
- **Small memory dump (64 KB)**
  `[...] this option requires a paging file of at least 2 MB on the boot volume [...]`
- **Automatic memory dump**
  `[...] contains the same information as a Kernel Memory Dump [...] Windows sets the size of the system paging file [...]`
- **Active Memory Dump** (implies indirectly)
  `[...] Active Memory Dump is similar to a Complete Memory Dump [...]`

So it seems, you can still configure the dump file without a page file set, but it is not guaranteed to contain all the data necessary for debugging.

As for configuration itself, all commands are outlined in the article [Configure memory dump files for Server Core installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-memory-dump)

Comment: Thanks. But the link in the last paragraph doesn't seem to be without a page file. It just doesn't have the page file managed automatically by the system. But +1 regardless.